# how to find significant predictors that is effecting correlation

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, feature-selection, pearson-r

I have a dataset with dimensions 10x53 where 53 patients(p1 to p53) as column variables and 10 rows of activity count measured for 10 days (d1 to d10). all the data is numerical.  sample dataset is as follows.

[image]

My objective is to group(clusters) 53 patients according  to their activity.
I know beforehand that 53 patients are taken from two groups, one with deceased and another normal group.

So far I created correlation matrix (53x53) using Pearson correlation. Then created a adjacency matrix by using some threshold. sample code
cormat <- cor((df.daywise, method = "pearson")

where df.daywise is 10x53 dataset.

Then I constructed correlation matrix and created adjacency matrix cor_matrix if the correlation between pi and pj is >0.7.

```
for (i in 1:53)) {
  for (j in 1:53)) {
    
    if(( cormatrix[i,j] >= 0.7 ) && ( i != j))
    {
      cor_matrix[i,j] <- 1
    }
  }
}
```

Let's say if p1 and p3 are correlated and grouped under 1 cluster, but p2 isolated because it is not correlated any other patient. Now my question is, how can I find out which feature (d1 or d2 etc) is the reason for p2 not to get (or insignificant correlation) correlated with any patient.

Comment: Why not cluster (something like k-means) on your $10$ variables? // How did you wind up with a $55\times 55$ correlation matrix?

Comment: My primary objective is to construct graph and then find clusters from the graph. Using 55x55 matrix I have created adjacency matrix with a certain threshold, say 0.7, then plotted graph using adjacency matrix. So after graph creation, I have few isolated nodes, but I am not sure how to identify the features for nodes isolation.

Comment: How do you wind up with $55\times55?$

Comment: Hi @Dave, I am not sure whether I understood your question completely. Let me explain (1.) initialize adjacency matrix of 55x55  (2) if(( cormat[i,j] >= 0.7 ) && ( i != j)) then set the entry (i,j) in adjacency matrix to 1. (3) plot the resultant adjacency matrix using graph_from_adjacency_matrix method. (4) if I apply any clustering algorithm on the resultant graph/adjacency matrix, i am expecting to get 2 groups of patients one with decease and another without.

Comment: Why $55$ instead of $53$ or $10$? I think the correlation matrix should be $10\times10$ ($53$ observations of $10$ variables), though perhaps I could believe $53\times53$.

Comment: oh. my bad. it is 53x53 not 55x55. somehow I was carried away with 55x55. thanks for correction. Now, it should be 53x53 that will establish the correlation among 53 patients. How to detect which feature is the cause of node isolation

Comment: I still do not follow why you would want $53\times53$ instead of $10\times10$.

Comment: How can I find whether p1 and p2 are correlated using 10x10 instead of 53x53? I believe 10x10 is helpful in finding correlation between 10 features but not correlation between 53 patients.

Comment: It would help if you edited your question to explain what you mean by "correlation between 53 patients".

Comment: please check now. I have added more details.